# Extract an information from the source code of an internet page with Qt Creator

Tags: html, c++, qt, qt-creator, qwebview

I'm doing a little project and here's what I'm trying to do :

I use the Qt ui with a webView widget and I would like to extract a specific information from the source code of a web page. It's the Order Code of a component.
The part I would like to extract is 1758990 in this example:

```
<div id="productDescription">


            <div class="brandLogo">
                <a href="http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp">
                    <img id="supplier_logo" src="http://uk.farnell.com/productimages/promo/en_GB/2217096.jpg" alt="MULTICOMP"/>
                </a>
            </div>


    <ul>
        <li>
            <strong>Manufacturer:</strong>
            <a href="http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp">
                MULTICOMP
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Order Code:</strong>
            1758990
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Manufacturer Part No</strong>
            MC0402B821K500CT
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="technicalData">

                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1859359.pdf" target="_blank" ><span class="pfIcon pfPdf" title="Technical Data Sheet (877.82KB) EN">&nbsp;</span>Technical Data Sheet (877.82KB) EN</a>
                </li>


    </ul>

</div>
```

I would like to use this order code and put it in a variable. The rest I would manage but I can't find the correct tools to find the code (which is never the same). I managed to extract the entire source code from the page with a toHtml() function and tried to export it to a textEdit but I don't really know what use it could have.
What should I use ?

Thank you in advance.

(also I'm sorry, I'm quite new at asking questions so forgive me if I f.. up the writing conventions)

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to use the findFirstElement() function but I can't find the correct query to extract only 1758990.
I can extract "Order Code: 1758990" with findFirstElement("#productDescription li:nth-child(2)") but I only want the order Code :.(

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, what you want is to extract the data from an html input? Check if this link helps you: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/35281

It extracts DOM data from a webpage ;)

Comment: Yes I've seen this technique before and tried to use it. But what I really want is to extract only ONE information (in this case, the order code of the component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a way (surely not the cleanest one but well...)

I have a button to retrieve the code :

```
void browser::on_Addtodbbtn_clicked()
{
    QWebElement code = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("#productDescription li:nth-child(2)");
    QString OrderCode = code.toPlainText(); // at this point, OrderCode = "Order Code: 1758990"
    OrderCode.remove("Order Code: "); // I remove the part I don't want
    qDebug() << "OrderCode:" << OrderCode; // Here you go

}
```

this page helped me a lot: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp